# How to add Leave a comment link in widgets_functions.php page

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add **Leave a comment** link in `widgets_functions.php` page.

The page is located inside `/wp-content/themes/framework/library/functions/`. When i used the function `comments_popup_link()` inside the page `widgets_functions.php` no such kind of comment link was shown after the end of the post.

Wordpress version is 3.5.1. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

*This tag must be within The Loop or a comment loop.*

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_popup_link

`comments_popup_script` looks like it can be used anywhere, but I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_popup_script